# How to convert python datetime to AWSTimestamp - appsync scalar type?

Tags: python, datetime, aws-appsync, awstimestamp

How to convert python `datetime` to `AWSTimestamp` - appsync scalar type?

```
Python format: 2021-07-14 09:11:48.563323
```

to

```
AWSTimestamp format: 1930-01-01T16:00:00-07:00
```

Comment: your "Python format" doesn't have UTC offset information while your "AWSTimestamp format" does have it. Could you please clarify?

Answer (score 0):

Use the below method to convert python `datetime` to `AWSTimestamp`

```
def convert_to_aws_timestamp(timestamp):
        return str(timestamp)[:-3].replace(" ", "T") + "Z"
```

Comment: that doesn't give the format you expect in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to user strftime from a datetime

For example something like

```
myDate.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z')
```

To obtain "2022-09-27T08:32:51.000Z"

But anyway your format looks strange, try to add more information, as was asked by FObersteiner